# How to pass multiple lines as value to Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to pass multiple lines as a value to my Ansible file But it's only just passing the **first** line.

```
cat slot_number.txt
slot4
slot2
slot1
slot3
```

My ansible file as below
update_bios.yml

```
tasks:
   - name: Powering off slot number
     command: "/usr/local/bin/power-util {{slot_number}} off"

   - name: Starting to update BIOS
     command: "/usr/bin/fw-util {{slot_number}} --update --bios"
```

ansible-playbook -l myhosts update_bios.yml -e "slot_number=$(cat slot_number.txt)"

I want to run my command like below:

/usr/local/bin/power-util slot1 off

/usr/local/bin/power-util slot2 off

/usr/local/bin/power-util slot3 off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit after understanding the question details:**

Map the slot numbers to a host:

```
cat slot_numbers.yml
slot_numbers:
    server1:
        -slot4
        -slot2
    server2:
        -slot1
        -slot3
```

After that distinguish between hosts in the playbook as follows,

```
tasks: 
    - name: Powering off slot number
      command: "/usr/local/bin/power-util {{ item }} off"
      loop: "{{ slot_numbers[inventory_hostname] }}"


    - name: Starting to update BIOS
      command: "/usr/bin/fw-util {{ item }} --update --bios"
      loop: "{{ slot_numbers[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

In this approach we are doing the mapping between hosts and slots in the slot_numbers variable file. Alternatively, you can define the variables as host variables also.

**Previous answer:**

Ansible understands yaml and json. 
Also, playbook needs to handle what happens with the data available to it via variables. So, if you want to loop through a list of slot numbers you have to tell your playbook to do exactly that.

Define your slot number file as follows:
In this file, you are creating a list of slot numbers and assigning it to the key 'slot_numbers'

```
cat slot_numbers.yml
slot_numbers:
    -slot4
    -slot2
    -slot1
    -slot3
```

Modify your  update_bios.yml to loop through the slot numbers you are passing,

```
tasks: 
    - name: Powering off slot number
      command: "/usr/local/bin/power-util {{ item }} off"
      loop: "{{ slot_numbers }}"


    - name: Starting to update BIOS
      command: "/usr/bin/fw-util {{ item }} --update --bios"
      loop: "{{ slot_numbers }}"
```

then use:

```
ansible-playbook -l myhosts update_bios.yml -e "@slot_numbers.yml"
```

Detailed documentation of how to use variables and playbooks can be found [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line)

Comment: thank you for your reply. it almost doing what I want to do But this task first is powering off all slot4 on all cluster, then powering off slot2 on all my cluster.
I want to power off slot4 on my first cluster, then power off slot3 on my second cluster.

Comment: ansible-playbook -l **myhosts** update_bios.yml -e "@slot_numbers.yml"        myhosts include my cluster.

Comment: cat /etc/ansible/hosts
[myhosts]
server1
server2

Comment: You need to define what slots should get executed on which server, for example, you can define  slot 4,2 as server 1 variables, slot 1,3 as server 2 variables. Basically, you need to tell Ansible somewhere the mapping, which server executes which slots

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
  vars:                                                                                                                                                 
    slot_numbers: "{{ lookup('file', './slot_number.txt').splitlines() }}"                                                                              

  tasks:                                                                                                                                                
    - name: Powering off slot number                                                                                                                    
      command: "/usr/local/bin/power-util {{ item }} off"                                                                                               
      loop: "{{ slot_numbers }}"                                                                                                                        

    - name: Starting to update BIOS                                                                                                                     
      command: "/usr/bin/fw-util {{ item }} --update --bios"                                                                                            
      loop: "{{ slot_numbers }}"
```